# function pointer of typedef

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*func)(int);

int add (int a)
{
        return ++a;
}

int getfunc(func myfunc)
{
    myfunc = &add;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
        int i;
        func myfunc;

        i = 10;
        getfunc(myfunc);

        printf(" a is %d\n", (*myfunc)(i));

        return 0;
}
```

I can't get what i want.
the result is " a is 0".
why is that??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're actually lucky that you get `a is 0` instead of a crash. The problem is that `getfunc` takes the function pointer by value, so the `myfunc = &add` inside `getfunc` has no effect on the caller at all. Try

```
int getfunc(func *myfunc)
{
    *myfunc = &add;
    return 0;
}
```

and in main:

```
getfunc(&myfunc);
```

Answer (score 2):

No question here, but you need to pass by address, not by value. the problem seems to be `getfunc(myfunc);`

Fix getFunc to:

```
int getfunc(func *myfunc)
{
    *myfunc = &add;
    return 0;
}
```

and call it with `getFunc(&myfunc);`

Answer (score 1):

It should be more like this (changes flagged with `<<<`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*func)(int);

int add(int a)
{
    return ++a;
}

func getfunc(void) // <<<
{
    return &add; // <<<
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    func myfunc;

    i = 10;
    myfunc = getfunc(); // <<<

    printf(" a is %d\n", (*myfunc)(i));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`myfunc` is a pointer. You created it but never assigned it a value. Then you call `getfunc` with a wild pointer!

Try this (your version, simplified):

```
int getfunc(func *myfunc)
{
    *myfunc = add;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
        func myfunc = NULL;
        getfunc(&myfunc);
}
```